# Difference between boundary fill and flood fill

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I'm quite confused as to how either flood fill or boundary fill color areas. Specifically when multiple colors are in play.

Let's say we have a polygon with a green border and a checkered interior (black and white). Which algorithm would fill the area correctly with green and why?

Definition of flood fill from the book:

> Sometimes we want to fill in (or recolor) an area that is not defined within a single color boundary. We can pain such areas by replacing a specified interior color instead of searching for a particular boundary color. This fill procedure is called a flood-fill algorithm.

Comment: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-boundary-fill-and-vs-flood-fill/

Comment: Due to the confusion in the names (not at all resolved by the article pointed by Henrik), please give a description of these two algorithms so that we can give a sensible answer. (IMO, flood and boundary fill are perfect synonyms, and there exists a very different technique for polygon filling.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would love to give the description but the book is quite vague on it as well. Hence me asking

Comment: Then I cannot ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Use Boundary Fill Algorithm.
If Keeps Coloring the region inward to outward until a selected boundary color is encountered.
in your case, The boundary color will be Green. So the algo will start from any inside point and proceed outward pixel by pixel until a green(boundary) is encountered. The black or white wont matter here.

Answer (score 1):

flood fill starts at any point inside the polygon, then spreads out in all directions filling pixels. A boundary fill finds the first boundary then traces the boundary, winding into the interior. Boundary fill is usually more complicated but it is a linear algorithm and doesn't require recursion, whereas a flood fill may use an unpredictable amount of memory to finish because it isn't known how many sub-fills will be spawned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not see multiple colors in the filling problem, but rather two categories: the "is-a-border" color or set of colors and the "is-not-a-border" ("inside") color or set of colors. It is a simple dichotomy, as if the image was binary.

In the case you mention, border is green and inside is black-or-white (you can also consider not-green).

Comment: So which algorithm would I use and why?

Comment: Flood fill or boundary fill, as they are the same.